# Is there a way to disable global warming and nuclear winter once the game has started?

Tags: freeciv

Suppose I started a game that has global warming and nuclear winter enabled. In mid-game, I decide that I want to disable global warming and nuclear winter. Is there a way to do this? I am enjoying my current game, and I don't want to restart from the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but it requires save editing.
In your save file (you may have to decompress it), change `"globalwarming",TRUE,TRUE` to `"globalwarming",FALSE,FALSE` and `"nuclearwinter",TRUE,TRUE` to `"nuclearwinter",FALSE,FALSE`.